# How to make SwipeGestureRecognizer on a UITableView more responsive?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have left and right swipe gesture recognizers on top of a table view. It works, but your swipe needs to be almost perfectly horizontal. It looks like your swipe needs to be between -10 and 10 degrees or so. How can I make that more like -35 to 35?

Comment: Are you saying you have custom swipes added to a tableview, in addition to the built-in swipes tableviews already support?

Comment: Technically the custom swipes are added to a view that has the tableview as a subview.

Comment: How do you plan to not have the left/right swipe of the view and the tableview interfere with each other?

Comment: The left right swipe should have precedence over the up down on the tableview. I want something very similar to what is in the Yahoo! stocks app.

Comment: TableView also has a left/right swipe to delete a cell.

Comment: @Randall let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2230/discussion-between-harkonian-and-randall)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to configure the `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` gesture to be more forgiving. Your only option would be to create a custom swipe gesture which does what you want.